# Redirect all URLs to other (external) site except for one path?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a working website (`http://www.example.com`) that (uses PHP-FPM) for which I want to redirect all incoming trafic to an URL on another website (`ttps://www.other-example.com/foo.html`) except one specific path (`/api`).

Here is the Nginx configuration I tried (put the PHP handling stuff in a dedicated `location` for `/api` and a `return 301` on `location /`):

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com;

    root /var/www/www.example.com;
    index index.php;

    location  ~ ^/api(?:/(.*))?$ {
        #return 418;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    
        location ~ \.php$ {
            #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

            # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

            # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
            # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_pass php;
        }
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.other-example.com/foo.html;
    }
}
```

But all my requests (`http://www.example.com`, `http://www.example.com/foo` and `http://www.example.com/api`) gets a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` with `Location: https://www.other-example.com/foo.html`.

I know the `location  ~ ^/api(?:/(.*))?$` works because if I uncomment the `return 418;` I get 418 responses for `http://www.example.com/api` requests but 301 for the other requests.

Comment: Where is `index.php`. Your `try_files` sends requests to `/index.php` which is not handled by the `/api` location. Should it `/api/index.php`?

Comment: I see what you mean, but the API is handled by the same PHP application that handles (handled in fact) the other pages, and it's entrypoint is the `index.php` located at `/var/www/www.example.com/index.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nginx processing goes as follows in your case:

1. Request to `/api/test_endpoint` matches the `location ~ ^/api(?:/(.*))?$` block.
2. In `try_files`, it matches the `/index.php$is_args$args` part. Since it is the last part, it triggers an internal redirect.
3. nginx restarts the processing with uri `/index.php`. This matches `location /` block, which triggers the redirect.

One solution to address the issue is the following configuration:

```
location  ~ ^/api(?:/(.*))?$ {
    #return 418;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location / {
    return 301 https://www.other-example.com/foo.html;
}

location = /index.php {
    internal;
    #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
    # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

With this configuration, nginx finds a match for `index.php` in step 3 of the request processing. The `internal` keyword prevents external requests to `/index.php` matching this block. External requests to `/index.php` will be served by `location /` block.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I know understand with the `try_files` made things go wrong.